# Store global string in mutable variable using LLVM API

Tags: php, string, ocaml, llvm

I'm making a compiler for a subset of PHP using LLVM and OCaml. Tutorials for string handling in LLVM is a bit lacking - at least I can't find any.

This is the code I want to compile:

```
<?php

$a = "foo";
```

This is my typed AST for above code:

```
[(Typedast.Stmt
    Typedast.Expr (Typedast.TUnit,
      (<opaque>,
       Typedast.Binop ((Typedast.Eq None),
         (<opaque>, Typedast.Lvar ((<opaque>, "$a"), Typedast.TString)),
         (<opaque>, (Typedast.String (<opaque>, "asd"))), Typedast.TUnit))))]
```

(`<opaque>` here just means that `pos` (position) isn't showed.)

This is my generated LLVM IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'mymodule'

@foo = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"foo\00"

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %"$a" = alloca i8
  store i8 0, i8* %"$a"
  store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @foo, i32 0, i32 0), i8* %"$a"
  ret i32 0
}
```

And my error message:

```
Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
  store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @asd, i32 0, i32 0), i8* %"$a"
 i8LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
```

The problem is that `i8* %"$a"` should be `i8** %"$a"`, as shown in an LLVM IR for a simple C-program:

```
int main() {
  char* str = "Hello, world!";
  puts(str);
  return 0;
}
```

which will generate this LLVM IR:

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [14 x i8] c"Hello, world!\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %str = alloca i8*, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1
  store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([14 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %str, align 8
  %2 = load i8** %str, align 8
  %3 = call i32 @puts(i8* %2)
  ret i32 0
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved (I really hope) by changing the code of allocation. Instead of

```
build_alloca i8_t ...
```

it should be

```
build_alloca (pointer_type i8_t) ...
```

I debugged this by editing the generated code directly and then compiling it with llc, to see what needed to change.